# Spring Boot Caching only using NoOp cache instead of configured Cache type

Tags: spring-boot, caching, yaml

I am adding caching to a spring boot project. The application.yml contains

```
  cache:
  cache-names:
    - cacheName
  caffeine:
    spec: maximumSize=100,expireAfterWrite=60s
  type: caffeine
```

@EnableCaching is on the main application and I have added @Cacheable("cacheName") to the method and it is NOT being called by another method in the same class.

In testing I see that the cache is of the type NoOp instead of Caffeine. I have insured that the correct imports (springframework) is used in all instances. Where else should I look to enable caching?

Answer (score 0):

try this .yml format

```
spring:
  cache:
    cache-names: cacheName
    caffeine:
      spec: maximumSize=100, expireAfterAccess=60s
```